# Visual Studio for Mac Cannot Resolve Assembly Reference EnvDTE

Tags: t4, visual-studio-mac

We are trying to use T4 Text Templates for code generation within Visual Studio for Mac. However when we save the file Visual Studio shows the error:

`Error: Could not resolve assembly reference 'EnvDTE'`

Others who are using Rider on Mac don't seem to see this issue so it seems to be specific to Visual Studio.

Where would we expect to find `EnvDTE` on a Mac?

Comment: EnvDTE is an API provided by Visual Studio on Windows. This is not something that Visual Studio for Mac supports. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte

Comment: This is working using Rider for Mac.

Comment: With a t4 referencing EnvDTE would need the EnvDTE assembly in the GAC, unless Rider is ignoring the error or somehow supplying it. Visual Studio for Mac does not have any EnvDTE assembly and neither does .NET nor Mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making Matt's comment above into an answer:

"With a t4 referencing EnvDTE would need the EnvDTE assembly in the GAC, unless Rider is ignoring the error or somehow supplying it. Visual Studio for Mac does not have any EnvDTE assembly and neither does .NET nor Mono"